# How can I update a lead that is being converted?

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, leads

We have a report that aggregates all of our leads based upon status.  The person who actually cares about this data would like to distinguish between a converted (status: qualified) lead and a converted lead that had an opportunity associated with it (custom status: qualified with opportunity).

I wrote a simple `afterUpdate` trigger which accomplishes this, however it doesn't work because you can't update a lead once it has been converted:

```
//Update the lead status if there is a related opportunity and the status hasn't previously been set
if (updatedLead.ConvertedOpportunityId != null && updatedLead.Status != STATUS_QUALIFIED_OPP) {
    updatedLead.Status = STATUS_QUALIFIED_OPP;
    update updatedLead;
}
```

I seemingly can't use a `beforeUpdate` trigger because the `ConvertedOpportunityId` hasn't been set so I don't know if there's a related opportunity.

Does anyone have an idea how I can accomplish changing the status once I know the lead has a related opportunity?

**Edit**

Here is the trigger:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {
    LeadTriggerHandler handler = new LeadTriggerHandler(Trigger.size);

    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.OnAfterUpdate(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

And the `OnAfterUpdate` method:

```
public void OnAfterUpdate(Lead[] updatedLeads) {
    this.VerifyLeadStatus(updatedLeads);
}

public void VerifyLeadStatus(Lead[] updatedLeads) {
    for (Lead updatedLead : updatedLeads) {
        System.debug(updatedLead.Status + ' ' + updatedLead.ConvertedOpportunityId);            

        if(updatedLead.Status == 'Qualified' && updatedLead.ConvertedOpportunityId != null) {
            updatedLead.Status.addError('You cannot use Qualified as a status value when creating an opportunity');
        }

        if(updatedLead.Status == 'Qualified with Opportunity' && updatedLead.ConvertedOpportunityId == null) {
            updatedLead.Status.addError('You cannot use Qualified with Opportunity as a status value when not creating an opportunity');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is practically in the question: you can't detect conversion in a "before update lead" database event, so you have no opportunity (pun intended) to alter the status of the converted lead during the conversion process. Instead, you will need to simply validate if the status is correct for the type of conversion that occurs:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after update) {
    for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Status == 'Qualified' && record.ConvertedOpportunityId != null) {
            record.status.addError('You cannot use Qualified as a status value when creating an opportunity');
        }
        if(record.Status == 'Qualified with Opportunity' && record.ConvertedOpportunityId == null) {
            record.status.addError('You cannot use Qualified with Opportunity as a status value when not creating an opportunity');
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that it appears that IsConverted is also set to false until the after update event fires during lead conversion.

**Important Note**

If your instance was created prior to 2008 you might not have the "[Enable Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_leadsettings.htm&language=en_US)" setting enabled.  If this setting is not enabled your lead triggers will not fire during lead conversion.  To enable the feature open a case with Salesforce and ask them to enable it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I haven't been able to get this to work.  The status value is always the old value on the lead; it never has the value specified during the conversion process.

Comment: @Ek0nomik Could you update your question with the full version of your trigger as it stands now? This code works verbatim in my developer organization, so I suspect there's simply some small tweak you need to apply to your version.

Comment: I added the code.  I wonder if it has something to do with the setting: "Enable Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert".  I keep seeing this mentioned online, but this setting doesn't exist in our instance.

Comment: @Ek0nomik That feature was removed, apparently-- it's now always executed from what I can tell (ran into this writing the test version). That aside, your code appears sound. You may need some debug logs to try and track down what's going on.

Comment: When I debugged the trigger with that `System.debug` call, I saw the original status (none of the "Qualified" values), but I also saw the converted opportunity id.  It's as if the trigger is executing after it has been converted, but before some of the conversion process has finished.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, but I edited the answer to include some information about enabling the "Enable Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert" setting.  This setting was disabled in our instance and once it was flipped on this code worked just fine.

Comment: Fair enough. I should have mentioned that, it's just been so long since I've had to enable that setting. They honestly should probably flip it on for all remaining orgs, since it's been six years...

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your requirement couldn't you use a formula field instead of code?

For example (I haven't tested this),
if (!ISNULL(ConvertedOpportunityId) && TEXT(Status) != STATUS_QUALIFIED_OPP,
    'STATUS_QUALIFIED_OPP',
    TEXT(Status)
)

Then you could use this field for your reports....